# c++20: how to move capture a class instance

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, move, capture

I want to construct a factory function for a class B, which needs a callback. The factory function gives a lambda to B, but this lambda needs an instance of another class A, which I want to create inside of my factory and move into the lambda. A is not copyable but moveable, so I would expect that this should be possible.

Unexpectedly, the compiler wants to use the deleted copy constructor of A rather than its move constructor (error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)').

Minimum example:

```
#include <functional>

class A {
 public:
    A() {}

    A(const A &) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A &) = delete;

    A(A&&) noexcept {}
};

class B {
 public:
    explicit B(std::function<void()>) { };
};

B b_factory() {
    auto a { A() };
    return B {
        [a = std::move(a)]() {
            // do something with a
        }
    };
}

B b = b_factory();
```

Compiler output:

```
$ arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi --sysroot=/home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi   -I../include -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -g   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-psabi -std=gnu++2a -MD -MT src/lib/CMakeFiles/traplog.dir/move_example.cpp.o -MF src/lib/CMakeFiles/traplog.dir/move_example.cpp.o.d -o src/lib/CMakeFiles/traplog.dir/move_example.cpp.o -c ../src/lib/move_example.cpp
In file included from /home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:59,
                 from ../src/lib/move_example.cpp:1:
/home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/std_function.h: In instantiation of 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = b_factory()::<lambda()>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]':
/home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/std_function.h:211:16:   required from 'static bool std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::_Manager_operation) [with _Functor = b_factory()::<lambda()>]'
/home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/std_function.h:677:19:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = b_factory()::<lambda()>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
../src/lib/move_example.cpp:27:5:   required from here
/home/.../poky_sdk_toolchain/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/std_function.h:176:6: error: use of deleted function 'b_factory()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const b_factory()::<lambda()>&)'
  176 |      new _Functor(*__source._M_access<const _Functor*>());
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/lib/move_example.cpp:24:26: note: 'b_factory()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const b_factory()::<lambda()>&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   24 |         [a = std::move(a)]() {
      |                          ^
../src/lib/move_example.cpp:24:26: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'
../src/lib/move_example.cpp:8:5: note: declared here
    8 |     A(const A &) = delete;
      |     ^
```

Can somebody explain this?

- edit #1: added full build output
- edit #2: removed unneeded code

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but if you have a function argument that you don't intend to use, like `cb` in the `B` constructor, you can simply omit its name. Like `explicit B(std::function<void()>) { }` There's also the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) [attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes): `explicit B([[maybe_unused]] std::function<void()> cb) { }`

Comment: As for your problem, what happens if you pass the `B` constructor argument `cb` by *reference* (either constant reference or rvalue reference) instead of by value? Since you pass it by value, it will be *copied*, including the captured `a` object. If you [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build-log (as text) into the question, then it would be easier for us to see what might be wrong.

Comment: And for future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And remember, whenever you ask questions about build errors, always include the full and complete build-log with the errors.

Comment: Thank you for your hints; I have added the full build output for reference.
Concerning your suggestion to pass cb per reference, I am not sure how to create this reference inside the factory function in a way that it will still be valid after the factory function has returned. Maybe you can give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the reason is that the type lambda you passed to `std::function` ctor violate `std::function` type requirement, which needs the passed `Callable` must be `CopyConstructible`. Since the captured type `A`'s copy constructor is deleted, it results that the lambda's copy constructor cannot be implicitly-declared.

Here's some reference from cppreference [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function):

> 5. Initializes the target with std::forward<F>(f). The target is of type std::decay<F>::type. If f is a null pointer to function, a null pointer to member, or an empty value of some std::function specialization, *this will be empty after the call. This constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless the target type is not same as function, and its lvalue is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R. The program is ill-formed if the target type is not copy-constructible or initialization of the target is ill-formed.

Also from the same page:

> std::decay<F>::type must meet the requirements of Callable and CopyConstructible.

---

#### Possible solution 1

If c++23 is acceptable to you, you can directly use `std::move_only_function`. https://godbolt.org/z/qhfd83955

#### Possible solution 2

You can write a custom naive function wrapper to handle your move only type, which is a simple type-erasure class with a function call operator, basically the same thing as chapter 9 of book "C++ Concurrency In Action":

```cpp
class TaskWrapper {
  struct impl_base {
    virtual void call() = 0;
    virtual ~impl_base() = default;
  };
  std::unique_ptr<impl_base> impl;
  template <typename F>
  struct impl_type : impl_base {
    F f;
    impl_type(F&& f_) : f(std::move(f_)) {}
    void call() final { f(); }
  };

 public:
  template <typename F>
  TaskWrapper(F&& f) : impl(new impl_type<F>(std::forward<F>(f))) {}
  void operator()() { impl->call(); }
  TaskWrapper() = default;
  TaskWrapper(TaskWrapper&& other) noexcept : impl(std::move(other.impl)) {}
  TaskWrapper& operator=(TaskWrapper&& other) noexcept {
    impl = std::move(other.impl);
    return *this;
  }
  TaskWrapper(const TaskWrapper&) = delete;
  TaskWrapper(TaskWrapper&) = delete;
  TaskWrapper& operator=(const TaskWrapper&) = delete;
};
```

And change `B` signature to:

```cpp
class B {
 public:
    explicit B(TaskWrapper cb) { (void)(cb); };
};
```

Then use it like:

```cpp
B b_factory() {
    auto a { A() };
    return B {
        TaskWrapper([a = std::move(a)]() {
            // do something with a
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and detailed explanation and the proposed solution; I can confirm that solution 2 compiles just fine. Unfortunately, C++23 is no option for me (yet).  Additionally, I certainly have learned something new about function objects...!
(Strange coincidence: Two days ago I received my copy of the mentioned book and can confirm a very similar the code snippet to be found in Chapter 9 "Advanced thread management". Without the hint I would never have found it, though...)